# CVS - At Which Branch is my Working Copy Looking?

Tags: version-control, branch, cvs

I have a few CVS WCs and, today, I took a look at one to make sure such-and-such code was present, but before I tell my colleague that it's okay, I need to make sure I'm looking at the right branch.

Somewhere I read that `cvs log` is the right way to go, so I `cvs log [filename]` and it listed all the branches in the project, but I wasn't sure how to see which branch I was using at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do a `cvs status` and look at the `Sticky Tag:` line.  there should be a branch listed in parentheses.

Sorry, I can't capture the output for you, thankfully it's been almost a decade since I touched CVS.

Comment: I envy you having not touched CVS.